# Google Analytics: Value ecommerce transaction value

Tags: google-analytics, goals

I have  problem with the ecommerce goals in google universal analytics. I would like to set up a URL goal to signal the completion of an e-commerce transaction. So the manual says that I have to leave the Goal Value field blank. But I can´t! It says that I have to put a number.

So if a set this field to "No" it doesn´t takes any value from ecommerce tracking and if I try to set up this field to "Yes", I have to put a value and it doesn't take the value from ecommerce neither...

Is it possible that this variable value option is not well implemented in Universal?? I'm stuck!

Answer (score 1):

No, you simply missunderstand the concept. Goals are there to track non-monetary goals (signups, registrations etc.) which may have a value nonetheless, so you can assign a fixed value.

A use case are for example if you do an adwords campaign to promote your newsletter - you can say "to me a subscriber is worth 10USD", so you'd enter 10 as goal value. Since goals values are used in ROI calculations etc. you'd be able to see in your adwords reports if on average you spend to much (or to little) money per subscriber.

If you need transaction values you have to implement e-commerce-tracking and use that.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

So in the Adwords statistics table in Analytics is not posible to see the value of you e-commerce transaction?

If you check the manual:
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1032415?hl=en&ref_topic=1007030

It says:
"If you’re tracking a transaction or purchase with the Ecommerce tracking code, leave the Goal Value blank. The actual value of the transaction will appear in the Revenue metric (not the Goal Value metric), and will come from the Ecommerce tracking code in your shopping cart."

Am I not understanding that properly?